# Swap input button for text while performing AJAX call

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I have a very simple problem. I'm trying to make an ajax call using the following button

```
<input type="submit" value="My Button" id="get" />
```

The problem is that I don't want a button, I need plain text to stand in rather than a button that gets clicked.

Full code. It's just from a small script.

```
$("#load_get").click(function(){
$("#result")
.html(ajax_load)
.load(loadUrl, "language=php&version=5");
}); 

//$.get()
$("#get").click(function(){
$("#result").html(ajax_load);
$.get(
loadUrl,
{language: "php", version: 5},
function(responseText){
$("#result").html(responseText);
},
"html"
);
});
```

Comment: Are you binding the event with Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I'm binding with Jquery. Also Josh, I was dumb enough before that I didn't know I was supposed to accept answers. I accepted an answer for my last question within an hour. Also, yes, I just need a hyperlink.

Comment: You should show us the jQuery. There are a few ways to do it depending on your method of binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example if I understand your question correctly:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.ajaxLink').click(function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); /*$.get()*/});
});
</script>
<a class="ajaxLink" href="#">text</a>​
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    var url=$(this).closest('form').attr('action');
    var formData = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).closest('form').attr('method'),
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){ ...},
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        { 
            alert("Error:"+xhr.status+" "+thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Your form could be

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" id="myform">
    <input name="one" type="text" value="input one" />
    <input name="two" type="text" value="input two" />
    <a href="" id="submit">Submit</a>
</form>
```